# Why can I reach Storyboard_a.storyboard and fail to reach Storyboard_b.storyboard in my framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, storyboard, cocoapods

I have a framework with two storyboards in it: StoryBoard_A.storyboard and StoryBoard_B.storyboard.
I can reach StoryBoard_A but not StoryBoard_B

I use my framework as a pod in my main project.
in my framework podspec file I have:

```Swift
s.source_files = "myFramework/**/*.{swift}"
s.resource_bundles = { 'myFramework' => ['myFramework/**/*.{storyboard,xib,xcassets}'] }
```

I know both storyboards are in myFramework bundle because:

1. In myFramework Build Phases, under Copy Bundle Resources I can see them both included.
2. In myFramework.framework I can see: StoryBoard_A.storyboardc and StoryBoard_B.storyboardc
3. When I 'pod install' myFramework as a development pod I can see both storyboards in the Project navigator of the main project

In myFramework, from ViewController_1 I initiate ViewController_a from StoryBoard_A.storyboard and ViewController_b from StoryBoard_B.storyboard.
I use the same technique:

```
let podBundle = Bundle(for: ViewController_1.self)
let bundleURL = podBundle.url(forResource: "myFramework", withExtension: "bundle")
let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL!)!
```

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoard_A", bundle: bundle)
let viewController_a = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController_a_id") as? ViewController_a
```

**but when I do:**

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoard_B", bundle: bundle)
let viewController_b = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController_b_id") as? ViewController_b
```

the app  crashes in the second line with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'StoryBoard_B' in bundle...

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
Since this was a piece of code that I inherited and I tried to merge it into myFramework I wasn't aware of the fact that inside ViewController_b.swift (the one that I was trying to initiate from the storyboard) there was:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Stroyboard_B", bundle: nil)
```

in the class scope.

I changed this to the bundle I created the same way as described above and that solved the problem.

I found this after I successfully tried to initiate other ViewControllers from this storyboard. That made me look inside ViewController_b to see how it defers than other view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Right click your app under Products in Xcode and explore it in Finder. Just check whether StoryBoard_B.storyboardc files are present.If files are not present, you have a different problem to solve.

If files are present, try accessing it like shown below.

```
let podBundle = Bundle(forClass: ViewController_1.self)
let bundleURL = podBundle.resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFramework.bundle")
let resourceBundle = Bundle(URL: bundleURL!)
```

Comment: Inside myApp.app I can see Framework directory within which reside all the frameworks that I use except for myFramework.framework. myFramework.bundle is found in the same path as Framework directory. 
When I look inside myFramework.bundle I can indeed see **Storyboard_A.storyboardc** and **Storyboard_B.storyboardc**
But that does not explain why I can access Storyboard_A.storyboard but fail to access Storyboard_B.storyboard. They are both contained in myFramework.bundle
Creating the Bundle object in the way you suggest did not work :(